# Upload files into Database

Tags: c#

I wanna create 2 texts box for (username and password), 1 fileUpload and 1 button to submit.
and I wanna make the admin to type the username and password then he can upload the file and submit (add it to the database).

everything it's work fine but my problem with fileupload...
**and I wanna save it in database  as(varbinary(max)).

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection IDB = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseConnectionString1"].ConnectionString);
    {
        SqlCommand IDBcom = new SqlCommand("Insert into Users(ID, Code, pdf) Values(@ID, @Code ,@pdf)", IDB);

                IDBcom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", TextBox1.Text);
                IDBcom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Code", TextBox2.Text);

           IDBcom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pdf", FileUpload1);

                IDB.Open();
                IDBcom.ExecuteNonQuery();
                IDB.Close();

                if (IsPostBack)
                {
                    TextBox1.Text = "";
                    TextBox2.Text = "";
                    FileUpload1 = null;
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: Why would you put `if (IsPostBack)` in a button click handler? Unless you're manually calling `Button1_Click` somewhere in your C#, then that check is useless.

Comment: varbinary(max) expects a byte array.  So open the file and use ReadAllBytes.

Comment: Side note: I would recommend against persisting files in the DB. Sql Server is a relational database, a file is unstructured data which makes it a poor fit for storing in a DB. A better option would be to store the file on disk and store a pointer to that disk in the DB so you can retrieve it when needed.